# A problem from Newtonian physics based in algebra

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have a solution - $0.1016$ meters - to a physics problem. I am told that it is incorrect. I furnish a solution, and I still think the solution is correct unless the mistake is with approximating the answer. The directions are to give the answer "to three significant digits."

**Problem**

Two beads with a mass of $1$ kilogram are at the ends of a compressed spring resting at the same distance above the $x$-axis on a smooth parabolic wire $y = x^{2}$. The spring has a natural length of $1$ meter and a spring constant of $5$ Newtons per meter. If the system is in static equilibrium, and if the acceleration due to gravity is $10$ meters per second squared, how far away from the $y$-axis is each bead? Use three significant digits.

**Calculation of the length of the compressed spring**

Since the natural length of the spring is $1$ meter, if the beads are stationary at $P = (x, \, x^{2})$ and $Q = (-x, \, x^{2})$ for some real number $0 < x < 1/2$, the spring exerts a force of
\begin{equation*}
\frac{5}{2} \Bigl(1 - 2x\Bigr) \, \boldsymbol{i}
\end{equation*}
away from the $y$-axis on each bead. If $\textbf{N}$ Newtons is the force exerted on the bead at $P$ by the wire, the magnitude of $\textbf{N}$ is equal to $\textbf{w}_{\perp}$, the component of the weight of the beads that is normal to the parabola at $P$. The weight of each bead is $10$ Newtons. Since the slope of the tangent line at $P$ is $2x$,
\begin{equation*}
\textbf{w}_{\perp} = \frac{20x}{\sqrt{(2x)^{2} + 1}} \, \boldsymbol{i} + \frac{10}{\sqrt{(2x)^{2} + 1}} \, \boldsymbol{j} .
\end{equation*}
So,
\begin{equation*}
\frac{5}{2} \Bigl(1 - 2x\Bigr) = \frac{20x}{\sqrt{(2x)^{2} + 1}} ,
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
1 - 2x = \frac{8x}{\sqrt{(2x)^{2} + 1}} ,
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
4x^{2} - 4x + 1 = \frac{64x^{2}}{(2x)^{2} + 1} ,
\end{equation*}
and
\begin{equation*}
16x^{4} - 16x^{3} - 56x^{2} - 4x + 1 = 0 .
\end{equation*}
Approximate solutions to this quartic equation are $-1.3805$, $-0.1811$, $0.1016$, and $2.46$. Only one of these approximations is between 0 and $1/2$: $0.1016$. So, $P$ and $Q$ are $0.1016$ meters from the $y$-axis.

Comment: Wouldn't "three significant digits" suggest $0.102$ meters?

Comment: How do you arrive at a weight of $10\,\text{N}$? The probelm description does not mention any gravitational field - and if Earth is implied, you better use $9.80665 \,\text{m}\text{s}^{-2}$ or at least $9.81 \,\text{m}\text{s}^{-2}$ instead of $10\,\text{m}\text{s}^{-2}$

Comment: My mistake. I will edit the post. It is assumed the acceleration due to gravity is 10 meters per second squared.

Answer (score 0):

*(Standard SI units implied throughout).* The potential energy stored in the spring, which is compressed by $1-2x$ to its length of $2x$, is $$\int_0^{1-2x}5s\,\mathrm ds=\left.\frac52s^2\right|_0^{1-2x}=\frac{5(1-2x)^2}{2}.$$
The potential energy of the beans is $2g x^2$. In equilibrium, the total potential energy
$$E(x)=\frac52-10x+(10+2g)x^2 $$
is minimal, hence
$$ 0=E'(x)=(20+4g)x-10.$$
We conclude 
$$x=\frac{10}{20+4g} \approx 0.344$$

Comment: There should be an explanation using only algebra.

Answer (score 0):

The forces on a bead are $5(1 - 2x)$ newtons horizontally and $10$ newtons vertically, which are balanced by a force at right angles to the wire. The slope of the wire is $2x$. By drawing the parallelogram of forces we see that $5(1 - 2x)/10 = 2x$. Hence $x = 1/6$ and $y = 1/36$. This is the same as Hagen von Eitzen's solution if we take $g = 10$ in the last equation (I don't understand where $0.344$ comes from).

Comment: If $0 < x < 1/2$, the spring exerts a horizontal force of $5(1 - 2x)$ Newtons. This force is shared between the two beads. So, the spring exerts a force of $(5/2)(1 - 2x)$ Newtons on the bead at $P$ that is away from the $y$-axis.

Comment: The slope of the normal line at $P$ is $-1/2x$.

Comment: So, the unit vector of the force exerted on the bead at $P$ is $\frac{-2x}{\sqrt{1 + 4x^{2}}} \boldsymbol{i} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 + 4x^{2}}} \boldsymbol{j}$.